# Assign custom action to Android Menu button, prevent default action at the same time

Tags: android, appcelerator

I have a main menu in my app that allows the user to do a set of specific tasks. On the app, I have a menu button akin to what Facebook have (three horizontal bars as a button). I'd like it to open when the physical Menu button on the Android phone was pressed.

Can this be done?

Comment: On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the action bar as a combination of on-screen action items and overflow options. Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated...what ur expecting then?

Comment: I don't want to use the Action Bar, as I want to keep the app consistent through iPhone, Android, BlackBerry and Windows Phone. So when the physical menu button is pressed it will trigger the menu I've built in the app.

Comment: this can be done with a native module.

Comment: Could you expand on this please?